# I am trying to use Fibonacci numbers to print out 15 numbers from the number the use inputs

Tags: javascript, html, fibonacci

I am wanting the user to input a number and from that number I want my javascript to output the next 15 numbers from the number the user inputted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fibonacci</title>
<body>
<P>Please input a number between 10 and 25</P>
<input type text="text" id="integer" />
   <input type="button" id="Enter" value="Enter" onclick="fibonacci_series(integer.value)"/>
    
   
   <p id="output"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fibonacci_series = function (n) 
{
  if (n ==1) 
  {
var loop = [0,1];
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = loop;
  return loop;
  } 
  else 
  {
    var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =s;
    return s;
  }
   
};
 
    

</script>


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Here is what it outputs when ran I input 10

0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55

I want to be able to input a integer between 10-25 and have it print the next 15 Fibonacci numbers from the user input.

Comment: Please provide a better problem statement than "what am I doing wrong". What is happening that shouldn't? What isn't happening that should? What error messages are you getting in the console?

Comment: You're right my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Non recursive solution, as you're already building the list of values, and with less risk of overflowing the callstack

If I understand the problem statement correctly, you are interested in printing the next 15 fib numbers, meaning when you input 10, you want to print from the 10th fib number to the 25th fib number

```
var fibonacci_series = function (n) 
{
  n = parseInt(n);
  ln = n + 15;
  s = [0 , 1];
  var i = 1;
  while (i < ln){
    s.push(s[s.length - 2] + s[s.length - 1]);
    ++i;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = s.slice(n);
  return s;
};
```

---

Given your comment below, this is trivial

```
var fibonacci_series = function (n) 
{
  n = parseInt(n);
  s = [0 , n];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 15){
    s.push(s[s.length - 2] + s[s.length - 1]);
    ++i;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = s.slice(n);
  return s;
};
```

Comment: Somewhat I want to have the user input a number between 10 and 25 so lets say the user prints 12. I want the number to add like 0, 12, 12, 24, 36, 60, 96, etc. all the way until we hit 15 numbers printed

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(fibonacci_series(10)));

var fibonacci_series = function (n, c = 0) {
  if (c == 0) {
    n += 15
  }
  if (n ==1) 
  {
    var loop = [0,1];
    return loop;
  } else {
    var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1, c + 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    return s;
  }
   
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

The `c` variable counts the callstack, so when it first calls the function, the given range by the user will be incremenetd by 15 (I believe this is what you're looking for).